# print parameters from a for loop in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So, i want to print the parameters of the script that meet some conditions :

```
t1=0

for i in $@; do


if [ $i == "-1" ] || [ $i == "-2" ] || [ $i == "-3" ]; then

t2=$(($t1+2))

echo $i $"$t2"

fi

t1=$(($t1+1))

done
```

If i call the script like this :

```
./name_of_script  -2 aaa -m bbb -3 ccc -4 ccc -1 ddd
```

i want it to print something like this :

```
-2 aaa
-3 ccc
-1 ddd
```

So i want to print the parameter that is -1 , -2 or -3, and each of the parameters that come right after them.
but i get this instead :

```
-2 2
-3 6
-1 10
```

I just can't turn 2, 6 and 10 into $2, $6 and $10 so i can print these parameters of the script.

Any ideas ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable (though dangerous) way to do something like that is via the use of `eval`:

```
eval echo "$i \$$t2"
```

In bash, there is a cleaner, safer way to do it using a feature called *variable indirection*

> ```
>    If  the  first  character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and
>    parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable  indirec‐
>    tion.   Bash  uses  the  value  of the variable formed from the rest of
>    parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is  then  expanded
>    and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the
>    value of parameter itself.  This is known as  indirect  expansion.
> ```

So in your case that would be

```
echo "$i ${!t2}"
```

However the canonical way to get the next positional parameter in a shell script is by using the `shift` builtin. So for example, you could do

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  opt="$1"
  case $opt in
    -1|-2|-3)
      shift
      printf '%s %s\n' "$opt" "$1"
    ;;
    *)
      printf 'unknown option: %s\n' "$opt" >2 
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Nevertheless, what you seem to be doing here is re-inventing the `getopts` builtin:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":1:2:3:4:m:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    1|2|3)
      printf -- '-%s %s\n' "$opt" "$OPTARG"
    ;;
    *)
      printf -- 'unknown option: -%s\n' "$opt" >2 
    ;;
  esac
done
```

then

```
$ ./name_of_script -2 aaa -m bbb -3 ccc -4 ccc -1 ddd
-2 aaa
-3 ccc
-1 ddd
```

Comment: I used the shift option in the end, but what i want was to use the  `echo $i $"$t2" ` expression. I wanted to print $a ,where a variable could be anything (ex: 1,2 ,3 etc.. ). I haven't found a solution to this yet.

Comment: @AlexP please see updates

Comment: nicely done ! very well explained and exactly what i needed. thank you!